# How to display result soap in list view xml odoo?

Tags: python, xml, soap, odoo, suds

i use python language to develop a new module of odoo and i use the library suds to consume web service wsdl :
it show me the following result

```
[(GroupSoap){
 active = True
 classNameId = 10005
 classPK = 10198
 companyId = 10154
 creatorUserId = 10198
 description = None
 friendlyURL = "/test"
 groupId = 10202
 liveGroupId = 0
 uuid = "9241b7bc-0c83-4aa5-8878-3dbf1bc43f6f"
```

I want to display this result in view xml odoo described in the following code:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="document_tree_view">
 <field name="name">document.tree.view</field>
 <field name="model">document_binov.document_binov</field>
 <field name="type">tree</field>
 <field name="arch" type="xml">
  <tree string="Documents">
       <field name="titre"/>
       <field name="description"/>
       <field name="type" />
  </tree>
 </field>
</record>
```

please help me